# How i generate json schema from mongodb result in java?

Tags: java, mongodb, jsonschema

I have a simple mongodb query and need the json schema of the result.

```
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    String database = "test_m0001";

    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(uri);
    DB db = mongo.getDB(database);
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(collectionName);

    try (DBCursor cursor = coll.find().limit(100)) {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject document = cursor.next();
            System.out.println(document);
            // --> generate json schema for document
        }
    }
    // --> merge json schema for all documents from query
```

What is the way to generate json schema in java? I looked into the Jackson JSON Schema Modul, but i don't find any answer. I don't have a model class, only the unknown structured documents in the mongodb collection.

Comment: Have you tried jsonsimple (https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)?

Comment: You might not have just one shape for the documents, so it may not be possible to come up with one schema for the data. There exist tools out there, like [mongodb-schema](https://github.com/skratchdot/mongodb-schema), for looking at all the different document shapes. Perhaps that will do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code. it may work

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    String database = "test_m0001";
    String json="";
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(uri);
    DB db = mongo.getDB(database);
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(collectionName);

    try (DBCursor cursor = coll.find().limit(100)) {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject document = cursor.next();
             StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
             JSONValue.writeJSONString(document.toMap(), out);
             json=out.toString();
             System.out.println(json);
        }
    }
```

It'll give the schema like :

```
{
    "_id": 5458 bee9d4ae9599b3ef2458,
    "author": "skc",
    "body": "My Programme",
    "comments": [{
        "author": "SCac",
        "body": "acsac",
        "email": "ascac"
    }, {
        "author": "Sitakant",
        "body": "ZScassc",
        "email": "Chaudhury"
    }],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 17: 26: 25 IST 2014,
    "permalink": "advcjnknl",
    "tags": ["asdcac"],
    "title": "advcjnknl"
} {
    "_id": 5458e a31157fe93550017831,
    "author": "SEEuewe",
    "title": "SkBaSmGaTuELeYUxRUIbFptrcyHKSJ",
    "body": "BGfaVSsHqolIfiwTpPOliWBHjkWlYa",
    "permalink": "skbasmgatueleyuxruibfptrcyhksj",
    "tags": ["tlpOe", "FbcGj", "pQlDf"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 31: 05 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e a31157fe93550017832,
    "author": "SEEuewe",
    "title": "DwCyowWKVxXUjpZUcFlHrhHpUzoKTh",
    "body": "zwkIAboiGhOejkHjdFuUAufcbyJapf",
    "permalink": "dwcyowwkvxxujpzucflhrhhpuzokth",
    "tags": ["YabrH", "qNUTy", "TmFwV"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 31: 05 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e a47157fe93550017833,
    "author": "CoPSPVk",
    "title": "NodErjzZvnRSzzWazYWLxGFslYcZDf",
    "body": "AfFGNtskOhVCzjvhQlGkJxGnYLrlVk",
    "permalink": "noderjzzvnrszzwazywlxgfslyczdf",
    "tags": ["IuPiv", "OubeB", "RnvWj"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 31: 27 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e a47157fe93550017834,
    "author": "CoPSPVk",
    "title": "oMKsjnkSXEtRlUcJEGBJgJbhkHcEzi",
    "body": "IvvcTOxCRpaJAzKoYisaCDKbeZnwsl",
    "permalink": "omksjnksxetrlucjegbjgjbhkhcezi",
    "tags": ["lqQhV", "mabGI", "xtPex"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 31: 27 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e a9d157fe93550017835,
    "author": "skc",
    "title": "Sitakant's Post",
    "body": "Here is the first Post of Sitakant",
    "permalink": "sitakants_post",
    "tags": ["JavaMongo"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 32: 53 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e b3e157f67f5ba156fa5,
    "author": "fNrSxIY",
    "title": "ZgjCajXasUObSUxRJvzpTYMtLiCjgH",
    "body": "fjzpLxOFRqVNDHmLwUePLMgSKcXMNA",
    "permalink": "zgjcajxasuobsuxrjvzptymtlicjgh",
    "tags": ["ftXfi", "sdTmw", "JhAtS"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 35: 34 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e b3e157f67f5ba156fa6,
    "author": "fNrSxIY",
    "title": "ImvrpnvgcvYEvYDqtGGXHVZONCPHbf",
    "body": "aaxGLzdiEPJVSLvrjsZdcwcgllMyLb",
    "permalink": "imvrpnvgcvyevydqtggxhvzoncphbf",
    "tags": ["FVFqj", "FlNNe", "vLmRo"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 35: 34 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e b48157f67f5ba156fa7,
    "author": "VAPNMXd",
    "title": "TljGJFvDqFQupouzmNFxPKvMnOJoJx",
    "body": "mucDhfFCNeBhpywYaCZhVSWZcVywoW",
    "permalink": "tljgjfvdqfqupouzmnfxpkvmnojojx",
    "tags": ["TqSdG", "IUfWr", "wPjlc"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 35: 44 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e b48157f67f5ba156fa8,
    "author": "VAPNMXd",
    "title": "LuqwcEFMHcwhbXnPHYDgtnCFxCPdUk",
    "body": "bKBYAfjJjtegKneCnUNVWUnbWcbhqW",
    "permalink": "luqwcefmhcwhbxnphydgtncfxcpduk",
    "tags": ["rXaFH", "hnbho", "RMQlm"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 35: 44 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e b59157f67f5ba156faa,
    "author": "TNBFjFx",
    "title": "hfYYvpEtlGOFhicEkXmwFGpPhNoUSP",
    "body": "TrShIejThHmjqrvoGpaEWGpPpEgYbK",
    "permalink": "hfyyvpetlgofhicekxmwfgpphnousp",
    "tags": ["OqTEO", "zYNIS", "vUpNa"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 36: 01 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e b59157f67f5ba156fa9,
    "author": "TNBFjFx",
    "body": "ldmqzeZBTtANiBlmVHTvqZhAeBLmXU",
    "comments": [{
        "author": "cGgBIQXTcrMG",
        "body": "VinmjjhWjyTJ"
    }],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 36: 01 IST 2014,
    "permalink": "kjlxmnkxzznomshgwldtlvfeflmmkf",
    "tags": ["LMfVJ", "PuUxy", "XZfpL"],
    "title": "kJlXMnkxZzNOMSHgWLdTlvFeflmMKf"
} {
    "_id": 5458e b5f157f67f5ba156fac,
    "author": "ofrjKsJ",
    "title": "nskhDjTuGFHXqTwqnLBBFSYcyStwEM",
    "body": "BmSDDQBbKVyjDmRjFJEVrulSBorMFL",
    "permalink": "nskhdjtugfhxqtwqnlbbfsycystwem",
    "tags": ["kvjic", "PnvyS", "ZVQND"],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 36: 07 IST 2014,
    "comments": []
} {
    "_id": 5458e b5f157f67f5ba156fab,
    "author": "ofrjKsJ",
    "body": "TzybDUtlJzkkBqWwaApplHkamFXkpM",
    "comments": [{
        "author": "QHwtRAJCNjvU",
        "body": "gqQIEmTaQsOs"
    }],
    "date": Tue Nov 04 20: 36: 07 IST 2014,
    "permalink": "abfqlmxkkdxiqpjuflvgqcocpxsxms",
    "tags": ["bzkEn", "IdXyE", "nblih"],
    "title": "abFQlmXkKdxiqPjUFLVgQCOcpxsXms"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want the data. I search the json schema, the description of document structure. Look at [json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/examples.html)

Comment: @ralfrausch ! Check the edited portion, your schema will come like this